# What do [0, rows) and [1, rows] mean? more specifically [ and )

Tags: math, range

I understand that it's from 0 to rows and from 1 to rows, but which is including and which is excluding?

Comment: What language(s) does this apply to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[ - including,
( - excluding

Example: [10, 15)
10, 11, 12, 13, 14

Example: (2, 4)
3
```

Comment: Note that in mathematical contexts, interval notation is always assumed to refer to a real interval, as opposed to the intervals of integers shown here. This can lead to confusion when a mathematician expects the interval (0, 1) to be a non-empty set.

Comment: Yes you are right about real interval in math. I assumed he is talking about integers because he counts rows.

Answer (score 2):

The [ is inclusive, ) is exclusive. So everything from 0 to rows, including 0, but not rows.

Sometimes this syntax is used instead: [0, rows[

Answer (score 1):

The `[` denotes a closed interval (i.e. inclusive) and the `)` denotes an open interval (i.e. exclusive). So `[0, 10)` means 0 through 10, excluding 10.